# How to retrieve leaf path in parent-child table in SQL Server with root ID?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I cope with type of storing `Tree` in SQL Server which has a specific method. In this method we have two tables like these:

**Location Table**

```
LocationID | Remark  
-----------+--------
    1        Tehran
    2        Azadi St
    3        Number5
```

**LocationParent Table**

```
LocationParentID | ParentID | ChildID | Depth 
-----------------+----------+---------+------
      1               1          1       0
      2               1          2       1
      3               1          3       2
      4               2          2       1
      5               2          3       2
      6               3          3       2
```

I desire have result like this:

```
LocationID |            Address
-----------+--------------------------------
      3        Tehran >   Azadi St > Number5
```

In `ParentID` and `ChildID` will store `LocatioID`. I wonder how can I retrieve root to child path with one query. I should say these tables maintain adresses for exmaple if we have : `City > Street > Alley > Number 6`.
Each of these has a separated `locationID` for instance city has one row in **Location Table** and so on.
Now I would have list of whole adresses? 
Is there any simple solution??

Comment: Is this a simple chain or might this be a tree too? It is unusual to store a `ChildID`, as a City can (and probably will) be the parent of many streets...

Comment: Provide sample data.

Comment: @Shnugo -yes this is a tree. If you pay attention to LocationParent table you see ChildID and ParentID.

Comment: @SasanK Yeah, but think about this... If you place a ChildID in the City which points to one street, this is `1:1`. The normal way would be the `parentID` only so many streets can point to their city, which is `1:n`...

Comment: Also provide desired results.

Comment: @Shnugo - No we have a lots of city, but city or street doesn't important. each of them just as a locations.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas - I have added desired result

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear for me and I really doubt, that this is the best structure for this...

Comment: Where do u have doubt?

Comment: You want to get 1 column `Address` or 3 separate columns?

Comment: Also why It's location id = 3?

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas - no I want all addresses. I just give an example but I need whole addresses like above format.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas - actually I want all (root to leaf) paths.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas - because Number5 has LocationID =3. Leaf's IDs are important in result.

Comment: @SasanK Your last comment *actually I want all (root to leaf) paths* let's me think, that the solution I posted a minute ago might solve your issue better than your approach...

Comment: @Shnugo -  _Tehran >   Azadi St > Number5_ is root to leaf.

Comment: @Shnugo Tehran is root and Number5 is leaf.

Comment: @SasanK Did you check my answer? This will provide any  location path you want...

Comment: @Shnugo I am testing that. if it give me your table it will be ok. But I want completely root to leaf. For example Germany > Berlin   is not useful for me.

Comment: @Shnugo - Germany > Berlin > Platz 1 > House in Platz 1 is OK. All of them must be like this.

Comment: @SasanK please comment to the answer...

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully understand your needs and I doubt, that the structure you provide is the best approach. Have a look at the following example of a `recursive CTE`. You can place a filter to get only the needed row:

```
DECLARE @LocType TABLE(LocTypeID INT,LocType VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @LocType VALUES(1,'Country')
                          ,(2,'County')
                          ,(3,'City')
                          ,(4,'Street')
                          ,(5,'House');
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(LocationID INT,ParentID INT,LocTypeId INT,Value VARCHAR(250));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
 (1,NULL,1,'USA')
,(2,1,3,'New York')
,(3,2,4,'Road 1')
,(4,2,4,'Road 2')
,(5,2,4,'Road 3')
,(6,4,5,'House 1 in Road 2')
,(7,4,5,'House 2 in Rouad 2')

,(8,NULL,1,'Germany')
,(9,8,3,'Berlin')
,(10,9,4,'Platz 1')
,(11,9,4,'Platz 2')
,(13,10,5,'House in Platz 1');

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT m.LocationID,m.ParentID,m.LocTypeID,m.Value,1 AS Lvl,CAST(m.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS LocPath
    FROM @mockup AS m
    WHERE m.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT m.LocationID,m.ParentID,m.LocTypeID,m.Value
          ,r.Lvl + 1
          ,r.LocPath + ' > ' + CAST(m.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM @mockup AS m
    INNER JOIN recCTE AS r ON m.ParentID=r.LocationID
)
SELECT * FROM recCTE;
```

The result

```
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| LocationID | ParentID | LocTypeID | Value              | Lvl | LocPath                                       |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1          | NULL     | 1         | USA                | 1   | USA                                           |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 8          | NULL     | 1         | Germany            | 1   | Germany                                       |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 9          | 8        | 3         | Berlin             | 2   | Germany > Berlin                              |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 10         | 9        | 4         | Platz 1            | 3   | Germany > Berlin > Platz 1                    |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 11         | 9        | 4         | Platz 2            | 3   | Germany > Berlin > Platz 2                    |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 13         | 10       | 5         | House in Platz 1   | 4   | Germany > Berlin > Platz 1 > House in Platz 1 |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 2          | 1        | 3         | New York           | 2   | USA > New York                                |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 3          | 2        | 4         | Road 1             | 3   | USA > New York > Road 1                       |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 4          | 2        | 4         | Road 2             | 3   | USA > New York > Road 2                       |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 5          | 2        | 4         | Road 3             | 3   | USA > New York > Road 3                       |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 6          | 4        | 5         | House 1 in Road 2  | 4   | USA > New York > Road 2 > House 1 in Road 2   |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
| 7          | 4        | 5         | House 2 in Rouad 2 | 4   | USA > New York > Road 2 > House 2 in Rouad 2  |
+------------+----------+-----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------------------------------+
```

The `LocationID` you store (e.g. as the `address` of a person) is the most detailled part (the *leaf-node*)

You can easily turn this logic to *bottom-up* (start off with the leafs)
You find a leaf by looking for all entries, which `LocationID` is not found as a `ParentID`.

### UPDATE I turned it around for you...

#### UPDATE 2 Added Depth

Check this

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT m.LocationID AS LeafID,m.LocTypeId
          ,m.LocationID,m.ParentID,m.Value
          ,CAST(m.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS LocPath
          ,1 AS Depth
    FROM @mockup AS m
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @mockup AS x WHERE x.ParentID=m.LocationID)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.LeafID,r.LocTypeId 
          ,m.LocationID,m.ParentID,m.Value
          ,CAST(m.Value AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ' > ' + r.LocPath
          ,r.Depth +1
    FROM @mockup AS m
    INNER JOIN recCTE AS r ON m.LocationID=r.ParentID
)
SELECT LeafID,LocTypeId,LocPath,Depth
FROM recCTE
WHERE ParentID IS NULL;
```

The result

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
| LeafID | LocTypeId | LocPath                                       | Depth |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
| 13     | 5         | Germany > Berlin > Platz 1 > House in Platz 1 | 4     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
| 11     | 4         | Germany > Berlin > Platz 2                    | 3     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
| 7      | 5         | USA > New York > Road 2 > House 2 in Rouad 2  | 4     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
| 6      | 5         | USA > New York > Road 2 > House 1 in Road 2   | 4     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
| 5      | 4         | USA > New York > Road 3                       | 3     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
| 3      | 4         | USA > New York > Road 1                       | 3     |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: your sample not compatible with my case.Where is @LocType in your query?

Comment: Can you use my tables name?

Comment: you should select on two tables. why I see just one table!

Comment: @SasanK Check my update. No, this is not 100% the structure you provide (because I think, that this structure is not correct). If you want, you can use my `@LocType` table to mark a location as a certain type... My current result table does include e.g. *USA > New York > Road 1*, because, there is no deeper object in this path.

Comment: Could u please replace names with my case?

Comment: All of them Tables and Columns.

Comment: @SasanK No, because your structure is not really working with your needs. There is no need for a second table. This is a *self-referenced-table* where you find the top nodes by searching for `ParentID IS NULL` and the leaf nodes by checking the existance of children...

Comment: @SasanK It is wrong to store a `ChildID` and it is wrong to store the `Depth`. This data is computed *on-the-fly*... Just imagine later changes to your data... This will lead into a hell of errors!

Comment: why doesn't depth true? tehran depth is 0 and number5 is 2

Comment: @SasanK You should not store data, which is computeable. Just count the `>` in your path and you know the depth too. Imagine a location, where you have to place one more location somewhere in between and now think about the changes you'd have to do, to provide data integrity. With my structure you just re-link the direct children to the new location and set its parentID to the former parent. Done!

Comment: @SasanK Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Since you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!