# Recursive Self JOIN SSMS but define lowest node

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good day all,
The code below defines a recursive self join, easy. However, using this method I can only define the most parentNode.  In my case, I want to be able to identify the most child node and be able to see all of his parents.

```
WITH q AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM [QA].[Node]
    WHERE ParentNodeID IS NULL -- This is where we define the most parent ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  m.* FROM [QA].[Node] m
        INNER JOIN q ON m.ParentNodeID = q.ID
    )
SELECT * FROM q
```

Could someone help me out :) it would be greatly appreciated. I want the ability to define lets say, give the query an id of 7, and have the query return in order from the most parent node being first and the the node we gave being the last entry.

For example, if the table is ancestroy and we have a column that references its self identifying the person dad.

I want the result to come back if i tell the query, 'WHERE ID = 50'

```
ID, ParentId, Name
(1, NULL, Grandpa),
(99, 1, Dad),
(50, 99, Me)
```

Comment: shouldn't "the most parent ID" be `WHERE ParentID IS NULL`? (note: you can't use `WHERE ID = NULL`...I mean, you can, but it's not doing what you think it's doing)

Comment: Sorry you are correct, i will edit the query

Comment: @Lamark, could you explain as to why its not doing what I am thinking its doing?   I should mention that the most parent node can have multiple entries.   So multiple rows could have parentID of NULL

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44256160/5089204) I provide an example for the same dataset top-down and bottom-up. The general idea is: *Find entries where there is no row with this item's ID as ParentId*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy example

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT, ParentId INT, Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
(1, NULL, 'Grandpa'),
(99, 1, 'Dad'),
(50, 99, 'Me');

DECLARE @StartForBottomUp INT=50;

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT * FROM @mockup WHERE ID=@StartForBottomUp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.*
    FROM @mockup AS m
    INNER JOIN recCTE AS r ON m.ID=r.ParentId
)
SELECT * FROM recCTE ;
```

I start the anchor-part at the item with the given ID and move up the chain.

Comment: I'm upvoting this one because it's better to create the CTE with the data already filtered

Comment: @Lamak, Thx, I hesitated to press "send" when I saw, that you'd posted a rather similar answer short before me, but continued due to this reason...

Answer (score 1):

This is the recursive CTE that you should be using:

```
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT ID OriginalID, ID, ParentId, [Name], 1 [Level]
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT q.OriginalID, t.ID, t.ParentId, t.[Name], [Level] + 1
    FROM q
    INNER JOIN dbo.YourTable t
        ON q.ParentId = t.ID
)
SELECT ID, ParentId, [Name], [Level]
FROM q
WHERE OriginalID = 50
;
```

[**Here is a live demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ffa1d58658e1e414ad896d10f2ff4d16) with the code.

And the results are:

```
╔════╦══════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ ID ║ ParentId ║  Name   ║ Level ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ 50 ║ 99       ║ Me      ║     1 ║
║ 99 ║ 1        ║ Dad     ║     2 ║
║  1 ║ NULL     ║ Grandpa ║     3 ║
╚════╩══════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: You should check @Shnugo's answer though, it returns the same results, but it should be faster